# localhost domain does not resolve properly on CodeIgniter and Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, apache, codeigniter

I am having a strange issue with Apache, Wordpress, and CodeIgniter. I have a laptop which I use for web dev, and it works fine. However, when I tried to access the sites hosted on the laptop's Apache installation through its IP address, the CSS would not load. When I examined the page source, it listed the path of the CSS file as `http://localhost/css/site.css`, even though I was accessing the page remotely.

I am running Wordpress and CodeIgniter on the same server, in different subdirectories. On the CodeIgniter header templates, I use `<?php echo base_url('/css/style.css');?>` to access the style, and on Wordpress `<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>`. Furthermore, when trying to access the admin panel on Wordpress, I am redirected from `http://10.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-admin` to `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin`, which breaks the admin panel too.

Strangely, this issue does not appear on the pure HTML sites, where I use a relative path for the CSS.

I suspect the problem lies with the WP and CodeIgniter config files, which have the domain of the sites listed as `localhost`. Another source of the problem could be the Apache config, but I have no idea where to start looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the CodeIgniter issue by going to the `config.php` file and setting:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

The Wordpress fix is temporary, until I can set up my DNS server to serve local hostnames. I put the Wordpress Home and Site URLs to the local IP address. This works for the moment, but if I switch networks, it will break again.